# User Experience for Comparing two Photos

Tags: user-behavior, android, user-expectation, iphone

I want to allow users to compare two Photos with some text to accompany placed next to each other and allow the users to vote.

I want to allow Users to be able to choose which of the two dishes they want to choose or which of the two places they want to visit by clicking and choosing 1 of the 2 options.

I am having issues bringing out the best UX on mobile screens. Having a Portrait mode doesn't allow the best UX as the images are too small if placed next to each other and keeping it one above the other makes doesn't give the best experience.

[image]
[image]

Would it be okay to allow the user to have a Landscape orientation when they go into the voting mode - is there any thing i should consider when the user is forced to stay in the landscape mode?

any Advice and recommendation here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If it's only a one to one comparison you may show those two images vertically, one on top and the other on bottom.

To win some space, you could put text over those images.

Moreover, you can propose some extra feature: use a swipe up and a swipe down to choose.
Or use a more classic link/button just like the desktop version.

[image]

Comment: Also, you could orient the images to encourage the user to rotate the device to landscape orientation.

Answer (score 2):

I am sure that there will be significant difference between vertical and horizontal position selection. The bottom image will have an advantage compared to the top one because of some human factors.

You can use the edge for selecting left and right by swiping left and right with thumb. Lastly, landscape usage can be also dictated to user.

[image: edge glued options]

Comment: You mean. forcing user to go Landscape mode is fine?

Comment: In games and some other application landscape using is already forced. if you are trying use browser than it is not going to work of course. And as an another solution, you can use the edge of the phone for showing the direction. The reason behind this decision is to have a more aligned data which can be used later for analysis. According to several papers the muscle movement of human changes the reaction time of user and also preferences of the user.

Answer (score 1):

Also, I would like to add two quick things,

Vertical / Horizontal

1. we can keep a toggle button to switch both the images quickly (let the user play with it), it should be real quick as to remember the previous image
2. give them an option to rotate (any direction either left or right) and keep the stop button
3. "[scrolling billboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dGSLJDcq47I)" just for an idea, it is faster and effective than above 1 and 2 points.

Comment: Adding to point 2, if the images rotate in place, individually, then rotating a **full 180°** from landscape to landscape (so not a mere 90° between landscape and portrait), would in effect switch the order of the images—the image from the left half would be on the right half, and *vice versa*.

Comment: great points. When you say stop button is it to stop from changing orientation?